# Stopping W3 Css-Javascript slider after two loops

Tags: javascript, css, slider

I am trying to make a slider having 5 images with help of W3 CSS and some javascript. I would like the slider to stop after 2 loops at the first slide and the first slide should remain static. After that, the user should be able to use the manual buttons for `previous slide` and `next slide`. I am new to javascript, unable to do that. Please help.

Following is my code (jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/dofhergw/)-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container " style="max-width:500px">

<div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading mySlides">
  <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide1">
  <img class="" src="img01.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </a>
  <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-
  16 w3-black">
    <a href="" 
  target="_blank" title="slide1">Slide-1 (read more)</a>
  </div>
</div>
.....
.....

<div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading mySlides">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide5">
        <img class="" src="img05.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </a>
          <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container   
             w3-padding-16 w3-black">
            <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide5">Slide-5 (read more)
      </a>
          </div>
</div>

<button class="w3-button w3-display-left w3-black" 
onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
        <button class="w3-button w3-display-right w3-black" 
onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>

</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 9000);  

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your carousel repeats itself every 9 seconds (9000 milliseconds) with the `setTimeout`. You can add a counter:

```js
var myIndex = 0;
var counter = 0;
var maxLength = 0;
var loops = 2;
var interval = 1000; //for testing purposes
function carousel() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".mySlides"); //using modern querySelectorAll
  maxLength = x.length * loops; //times 2 for two loops    

  //optimalization here - borrowing Array forEach to loop over node list
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(x, function(element) {
    element.style.display = "none";
  });

  counter++; //adding counter
  if (myIndex >= x.length) {
    myIndex = 0
  }; //reset this to zero indexing
  x[myIndex].style.display = "block"; //show the slide
  if (counter <= maxLength) //ie counter <= 10, execute 
  {
    myIndex++; //add index with every pass
    setTimeout(carousel, interval);
  }
  else
  {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(x, function(element) {
     element.classList.remove("w3-animate-fading"); //remove the fading
   });  
  }
  

}

carousel();
```

```css
.w3-content.w3-display-container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

button.w3-button.w3-display-left.w3-black {
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}

button.w3-button.w3-display-right.w3-black {
  position: relative;
  right: -118px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container " style="max-width:150px">

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading mySlides">
    <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide1">
      <img class="" src="img01.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </a>
    <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large  w3-container w3- padding-16 w3-black">
      <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide1">Slide-1 (read more)</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading mySlides">
    <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide2">
      <img class="" src="img02.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </a>
    <div class="w3-display-bottomright w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16     w3-black">
      <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide2">Slide-2 (more)</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading mySlides">
    <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide3">
      <img class="" src="img03.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </a>
    <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-large w3-container 
           w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide3">Slide-3 (read more)</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading mySlides">
    <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide4">
      <img class="" src="img04.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </a>
    <div class="w3-display-topright w3-large w3-container 
           w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide4">Slide-4 (read more)</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading mySlides">
    <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide5">
      <img class="" src="img05.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </a>
    <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container   
           w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide5">Slide-5 (read more)</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="w3-button w3-display-left w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-display-right w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>

</div>
```

When the counter is reached, the carousel function will not be set up to be executed anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But your code is not working. Please see my code at this fiddle - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dofhergw/) and your code at [link](https://jsfiddle.net/896cxyhq/)

Comment: Yes, it is working now. But after stopping after 2 loops at slide 1, the slide 1 starts to fade in and fade out. Maybe I was not clear enough in my post. I would like the slider to remain static after 2 loops. And also after 2 loops, i would like the user to be able to use the previous and next buttons. Can you please try to do that ? Thanks in advance. @Mouser

Comment: Well it does that now. But `plusDivs` is something you need to do by yourself. I've answered the question and put you on the right track. Upvote would be nice.

Comment: Can you make the slide-1 to remain static after end of 2 loops instead of the slide-1 fading in and out ?

Comment: Thanks for updating the code for removing the fading . Have upvoted your answer.